# Server logs for Postgres Flex server?

Tags: azure, azure-postgresql

we migrated to the postgres flex server recently. We've got the problem that some of us could not connect to the DB, altough we set the correct ip for them within our firewall rules.

So for further investigating we want to look into the server logs and find out which ip was used for accessing the db. With the 'old' server there were server logs available but for the flexible solution i found no option. We already add a diagnostic setting and sending all our logs to a log analytic workspaces, but was not able to find anything. Maybe we used a wrong query.

Someone an idea how to find these server logs and/or how to find out which ip tries to get access ?